# String.Format is not formatting correctly

Tags: vb.net, string.format

I have the following code and I can't get it to format properly. It is ignoring my formats. For example sOrderNo is not 10 zeros, it is only 1 zero. What am I doing wrong here?

```
sKey = String.Format("{0:D10} {1:00} {2} {3} {4} {5}   {6} {7} {8:000.0000} {9:000.0000}",
       sOrderNo, sItem, sSpecies, sSpSort, rs.Fields("UsageCode").Value,
       rs.Fields("Cure").Value, sGrade, sSurface, 
       rs.Fields("TkFactor").Value,rs.Fields("WdFactor").Value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> sOrderNo is not 10 zeros,

The necessary format string for that is `D10`, not `10D`. Idle curio: [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#DFormatString) implies only up to D9 is possible, but it works with 10 and [all the way to 99 even](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fNmFfb)

```
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Hello World {0:D99}", 12345));
```

Comment: {0:D10} does not work either, and neither does {1:D2} or {1:00} work for sItem. I was able to get what I need by: "{0} {1} etc..., ", Cint(sOrderNo).ToString("D10"), Cint(sItem).ToString("D2"),  etc...  Just don't understand why the original code above even with the corrected D10 doesn't work.

Comment: sOrderNo needs to be a number, not a numerical string..

Comment: In my "all the way to 99" link you'll note I pass an integer 12345, not a string "12345". The only thing you can do with strings is left or right pad them with spaces, by using eg `{0:-50}` or `{0:50}` for "pad to 50 wide", the minus/plus dictating the alignment of the string in the field